# Generate video thumbnails on client side

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I have `videojs` and `videojs-markers` plugin and when the marker is shown up I also want to display thumbnail this particular video moment. But I have no idea how can I generate this thumbnails.
I found solution how to draw thumbnail of current video moment:

```
function capture(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
}
```

But I'm looking for how to generate images on moment I don't reach.